# __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Please help me out. In this simple tkinter program to create a button, I have provided all three arguments, yet the error regarding positional arguments is coming up on the screen. Sorry for my poor English.

```
from tkinter import *

class Button:
def __init__(self, row, column, frame):
    self.row = row
    self.column = column
    b = Button(frame).grid(row = self.row, column = self.column)

tk = Tk()
b1 = Button(row = 1, column = 1, frame = tk)
tk.mainloop()
```

And the error:

> RESTART: C:\Users\vnira\Documents\python.projects\Flappy Bird\whiteboard.py
>  
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\vnira\Documents\python.projects\Flappy Bird\whiteboard.py", line 11, in 
>      b1 = Button(row = 1, column = 1, frame = tk)
>    File "C:\Users\vnira\Documents\python.projects\Flappy Bird\whiteboard.py", line 7, in **init**
>    Button(frame).grid(row = self.row, column = self.column)
>   TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'column' and 'frame'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

class Buttons:
    def __init__(self, row, column, frame):
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        b = Button(frame).grid(row = self.row, column = self.column)

tk = Tk()
b1 = Buttons(row = 1, column = 1, frame = tk)
tk.mainloop()
```

You created a class Button when tkinter has a class Button. Using your own variable names might help :) I imagine it was trying to recursively make an instance of the Button class you created, instead of making an instance of the Button class that is inside the tkinter module.

Answer (score 2):

In the `__init__` in the `Button` class you are trying to work on a new instance of the `Button` class:

```
b = Button(frame)
```

Since `button.__init__` takes 3 arguments, `row, column, frame` the script fails. If you did pass `row` and `column` as well, you would run into recursion issues where you infinitely create new instances of `Button`.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments and other answer, `tkinter` has its own `Button` class which you are overwriting, which is why you should try to avoid doing

```
from tkinter import *
```

and instead just `import tkinter` and call `tkinter.Button`.

Comment: It's also important to mention that by creating a class called `Button`, they are destroying the tkinter class of the same name.